# Getting error in linking a source folder in eclipse maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created an empty maven project and it created a folder structure `src/main/java`.
Now I want to link source from my local repo to this `src/main/java`.

If I go to `buildpath->link source`, and name the folder as `src/main/java`, I get the

> **folder already exists error**

If I delete the folder and then do the same step, I get following error.

[image]

What is the best way to go forward?

I cannot change the project structure in the repo location and copying the folder to my workspace would mean manually merging changes later.

**EDIT** Folder Structure:

[image]

And build part of my **pom.xml**:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>java</sourceDirectory>    
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <excludes>
                <exclude>**/old/**/*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>java/com/**/*.java</include>            
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/old/**/*.java</exclude>                 
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>com.start.Start</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure your project source with `buildpath->link source` it is just a configuration for eclipse. All it does is adding a linked source entry in the eclipse .project file. Maven does not know anything about this configuration. When you try to install your project with this configuration (with maven), you will not see any source code in the installed artifact.

If you have to do it this way add following to your pom.xml file. This will inform maven that you are using a different project folder structure. (this configuration is not recomended, but in your case it is usable)

```
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>Reletive path to source folder</sourceDirectory>
   .....
</build>
```

At eclipse side just give folder the name, that your sources main folder name. (like "Source")

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

Comment: I already tried this. But I get "no sources to compile" message & resultant jar is empty. When I searched for that problem, all the solutions suggested using standard maven directory structure

Comment: @theLearner which command gives this error message. I am able to install jar with compiled sources with this setup.

Comment: When I right click-run as-maven build. Build is successful but the message is shown - no sources to compile

Comment: @theLearner Can you add folder structure which you pass to maven sourcedirectory.

Comment: Added pom.xml and folder structure